# php цикл foreach внутри js кода

Tags: php, javascript

в index.html файле есть обычный script, внутри которого js массив (который генерируется циклом foreach из php).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cams = [
        <?php foreach ((array) $this->data['video_streams'] as $video_stream): ?>
        {
            type : "html",
            title : "<?php echo addslashes($video_stream['name']); ?>",
            content : "<?php echo addslashes($video_stream['html']); ?>",
        },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    ];
</script>
```

Суть в том, что у меня в переменной **$video_stream['html']** хранится ещё один **script**, который воспроизводится прямо из массива. Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете, как его можно экранировать? Я пытался добавить **addslashers()**, но он (скрипт) всё равно воспроизводится, но на сей раз с ошибками из-за слешей.

Comment: а вы не хотите сделать что-нибудь а-ля `var cams = <?= json_encode($this->data['video_streams']) ?>` ? ибо генерить массивы циклами на пхп это не как-то не очень :)

Comment: @teran на самом деле, я давно уже всё сделал обычным аякс запросом, переключение камер. Но увы, руководителю такой метод не понравился и заставил делать заранее подготовленным массивом на js. Хотя видимой разницы в загрузке вообще нет.

Comment: @teran однако, ваш метод отлично сработал, спасибо :)

Comment: если разницы нет, а данные можно подготовить сразу, то зачем слать на сервер лишние запросы? с этой точки зрения руководитель прав.

Comment: @teran никто и не спорил, полностью согласен.